# Ошибка при отправке запроса python requests

Tags: python, requests

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Host': 'api-gw.youla.io',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96", "Yandex";v="22"',
    'x-app-id': 'web/3',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'x-uid': '61fbadfb8616a',
    'authorization': '',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'x-youla-splits': '8a=7|8b=3|8c=0|8m=0|8v=0|8z=0|16a=0|16b=0|64a=4|64b=0|100a=57|100b=99|100c=0|100d=0|100m=0',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'uid': '61fbadfb8616a',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.116 YaBrowser/22.1.1.1544 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36',
    'appId': 'web/3',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'Origin': 'https://youla.ru',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Referer': 'https://youla.ru/all/zhenskaya-odezhda',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru,en;q=0.9',
}

data = '{"operationName":"catalogProductsBoard","variables":{"sort":"DEFAULT","attributes":[{"slug":"categories","value":["zhenskaya-odezhda"],"from":null,"to":null}],"datePublished":null,"location":{"latitude":null,"longitude":null,"city":null,"distanceMax":null},"search":"","cursor":"{\\page\\\\:0,\\totalProductsCount\\\\:30,\\dateUpdatedTo\\\\:1643884041}"},"query":"query catalogProductsBoard($sort: Sort, $attributes: [AttributeItem!], $location: LocationInput, $cursor: Cursor!, $search: String, $datePublished: DateInput) {\\n  feed(input: {sort: $sort, attributes: $attributes, location: $location, search: $search, datePublished: $datePublished}, after: $cursor) {\\n    items {\\n      ... on BannerItem {\\n        type\\n        banner {\\n          title\\n          description\\n          buttonTitle\\n          imageURL\\n          __typename\\n        }\\n        __typename\\n      }\\n      ...PromotedProductBoardCard\\n      ...ProductBoardCard\\n      __typename\\n    }\\n    pageInfo {\\n      cursor\\n      hasNextPage\\n      personalSearchId\\n      productsAnalytics {\\n        searchId\\n        __typename\\n      }\\n      __typename\\n    }\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n}\\n\\nfragment PromotedProductBoardCard on PromotedProductItem {\\n  product: productPromoted {\\n    ...ProductCardFragment\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n  productAnalytics {\\n    promotionType\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n  __typename\\n}\\n\\nfragment ProductCardFragment on Product {\\n  id\\n  categoryId: category\\n  subcategoryId: subcategory\\n  price {\\n    origPrice {\\n      price\\n      __typename\\n    }\\n    realPrice {\\n      price\\n      __typename\\n    }\\n    realPriceText\\n    discount\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n  url\\n  images {\\n    id\\n    num\\n    url\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n  name\\n  location {\\n    cityName\\n    city\\n    addressText\\n    description\\n    latitude\\n    longitude\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n  isPromoted\\n  favorite {\\n    enabled\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n  deliveryAvailable\\n  paymentAvailable\\n  branding {\\n    imageUrl\\n    rating\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n  __typename\\n}\\n\\nfragment ProductBoardCard on ProductItem {\\n  product {\\n    ...ProductCardFragment\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n  productAnalytics {\\n    promotionType\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n  __typename\\n}\\n"}'

response = requests.post('https://api-gw.youla.io/federation/graphql', headers=headers, data=data)
```

Ошибка при отправке запроса в чем может быть проблема?

Вот сама ошибка

```
Unexpected token : in JSON at position 289
```

Comment: Ругается на запятую вот здесь: `"cursor":"{\\page\\\\:0,` Вы уверены, что это правильный `JSON`? page почему без кавычек, там не должны быть они?

Answer (score 2):

Отвечу комментарию, JSON верен. Проблема со слэшами, как они интерпретируются при `loads()` методе библиотеки `json`.

Пример из [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

```py
>>> json.loads('"\\"foo\\bar"')
'"foo\x08ar'
```

Лучший способо этого избежать, это использовать литерал `r` для строки. Приведу пример на строке где у вас ломается

```
>>> import json
>>> a = '{"cursor": "{\\page\\\\:0,\\totalProductsCount\\\\:30,\\dateUpdatedTo\\\\:1643884041}"}'
>>>json.loads(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 1 column 14 (char 13)
```

А теперь строку запишу так,

```
>>> z = r'{"cursor": "{\\page\\\\:0,\\totalProductsCount\\\\:30,\\dateUpdatedTo\\\\:1643884041}"}'
>>> res = json.loads(z)
>>> print(res)
{'cursor': '{\\page\\\\:0,\\totalProductsCount\\\\:30,\\dateUpdatedTo\\\\:1643884041}'}
```

Все работает

Если взять ваши данные и попробовать провернуть то же самое со всей строкой `data`

```
>>> data = r'{"operationName":"catalogProductsBoard","variables":{"sort":"DEFAULT","attributes":[{"slug":"categories","value":["zhenskaya-odezhda"],"from":null,"to":null}],"datePublished":null,"location":{"latitude":null,"longitude":null,"city":null,"distanceMax":null},"search":"","cursor":"{\\page\\\\:0,\\totalProductsCount\\\\:30,\\dateUpdatedTo\\\\:1643884041}"},"query":"query catalogProductsBoard($sort: Sort, $attributes: [AttributeItem!], $location: LocationInput, $cursor: Cursor!, $search: String, $datePublished: DateInput) {\\n  feed(input: {sort: $sort, attributes: $attributes, location: $location, search: $search, datePublished: $datePublished}, after: $cursor) {\\n    items {\\n      ... on BannerItem {\\n        type\\n        banner {\\n          title\\n          description\\n          buttonTitle\\n          imageURL\\n          __typename\\n        }\\n        __typename\\n      }\\n      ...PromotedProductBoardCard\\n      ...ProductBoardCard\\n      __typename\\n    }\\n    pageInfo {\\n      cursor\\n      hasNextPage\\n      personalSearchId\\n      productsAnalytics {\\n        searchId\\n        __typename\\n      }\\n      __typename\\n    }\\n    __typename\\n  
}\\n}\\n\\nfragment PromotedProductBoardCard on PromotedProductItem {\\n  product: productPromoted {\\n    ...ProductCardFragment\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n  productAnalytics {\\n    promotionType\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n  __typename\\n}\\n\\nfragment ProductCardFragment on Product {\\n  id\\n  categoryId: category\\n  subcategoryId: subcategory\\n  price {\\n    origPrice {\\n      price\\n      __typename\\n    }\\n    realPrice {\\n      price\\n      __typename\\n    }\\n    realPriceText\\n    discount\\n 
   __typename\\n  }\\n  url\\n  images {\\n    id\\n    num\\n    url\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n  name\\n  location {\\n    cityName\\n    city\\n    addressText\\n    description\\n    latitude\\n    longitude\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n  isPromoted\\n  favorite {\\n    enabled\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n  deliveryAvailable\\n  paymentAvailable\\n  branding {\\n    imageUrl\\n    rating\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n  __typename\\n}\\n\\nfragment ProductBoardCard on ProductItem {\\n  product {\\n    ...ProductCardFragment\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n  productAnalytics {\\n    promotionType\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n  __typename\\n}\\n"}'
>>> result = json.loads(data)
>>> print(result["variables"])     
{'sort': 'DEFAULT', 'attributes': [{'slug': 'categories', 'value': ['zhenskaya-odezhda'], 'from': None, 'to': None}], 'datePublished': None, 'location': {'latitude': None, 
'longitude': None, 'city': None, 'distanceMax': None}, 'search': '', 'cursor': '{\\page\\\\:0,\\totalProductsCount\\\\:30,\\dateUpdatedTo\\\\:1643884041}'}
```

**UPD** Добавлю, что вы можете формировать словарь, который будете передавать в тело запроса, а не строку, как сейчас.

```py
data = {
    "operationName": "catalogProductsBoard",
    "variables": {
        "sort": "DEFAULT",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "slug": "categories",
                "value": [
                    "zhenskaya-odezhda"
                ],
                "from": None,
                "to": None
            }
        ],
        "datePublished": None,
        "location": {
            "latitude": None,
            "longitude": None,
            "city": None,
            "distanceMax": None
        },
        "search": "",
        "cursor": "{\\page\\\\:0,\\totalProductsCount\\\\:30,\\dateUpdatedTo\\\\:1643884041}"
    },
}
```

И использовать тот же самый запрос, но я просто поменяю ulr  и отправлю

```py
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.post('https://youtube.com', data=data)
>>> response
<Response [400]>
```

То есть сам запрос ушел, а вот сервер не принял его и дал мне 400 ответ